# How do I find the spaces in an HTML page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to find the spaces between each and every word in an HTML page using JavaScript.

Example:

This is sample text

In this example, there is a space between "this" and "is" and each following word.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you need to do once you find it?

Comment: i Need to highlight using css.

Comment: You won't be able to highlight with CSS as there's no selector on which to apply it.

Comment: Okey... So then how can i achieve this functionality?

Comment: You'd have to find the spaces using a technique below, then wrap each space with an element, such as `span`.

Comment: Actually my original requirement is, in MS word we have a functionality to find the space using the show/hide(The Icon next to sort in home menu).The same functionality i am implementing using Java script.. So please share your idea for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Regex to achieve this:

```
document.body.innerHTML.match(/\s/g);
```

http://regexr.com/39al2

Answer (score 1):

OK. Now I have read the comments here is the entire code it will highlight all text on a page

```
recurseDomChildren(document.documentElement, true);

function recurseDomChildren(start, output)
{
    var nodes;
    if(start.childNodes)
    {
        nodes = start.childNodes;
        loopNodeChildren(nodes, output);
    }
}

function loopNodeChildren(nodes, output)
{
    var node;
    for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
    {
       node = nodes[i];
       if(output)
       {
            outputNode(node);
       }
       if(node.childNodes)
       {
            recurseDomChildren(node, output);
       }
    }
}

function outputNode(node)
{
    var whitespace = /^\s+$/g;
    if(node.nodeType === 1)
    {
        console.log("element: " + node.tagName);  
    }else if(node.nodeType === 3)
    {
        //clear whitespace text nodes
        node.data = node.data.replace(whitespace, "");
        if(node.data)
        {
        debugger;
        node.parentElement.style.background="yellow";
        console.log("text: " + node.data); 
    }  
}  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ee5X6/35/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a right answer but just try

```
var str = "this is sample text";
```

first trim it.

```
str = str.trim();
```

split text by space(" ")

```
var array = str.split(" ");
```

white space would be array.length -1

Answer (score 0):

That is quite simple, without knowing what you need to do exactly, here is some code that will strip out all the HTML tags and give you the spaces and the words, then you can split that down so that you get all the spaces and words in an array, you can then walk that array and do as you please:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var words = body.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").split(" ");
```